# SQL find all groups with at least N matching elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have a system that collects SERPs (search engine results) and stores them in the database. I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2.

For every given keyword there is a SERP result group that contains 10 SERP elements.

```
Keyword -> 
    SERP Group ->
        - SERP item
        - SERP item
        - ... (3-10)
```

Entities

```
public class SerpResultsGroup
{
    public SerpResultsGroup()
    {
        SerpResults = new List<SerpResult>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int KeywordId { get; set; }
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SerpResult> SerpResults { get; set; }
}

public class SerpResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public int SerpResultsGroupId { get; set; }
    public SerpResultsGroup SerpResultsGroup { get; set; }
}
```

DB schema
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et9Ac.png)

Now i need to combine all SERP groups (or SERP items) and find such groups where at least N(3) SERP items are identical.

Here is a picture to illustrate the logic.
[Grouping algorithm, illustration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whbwe.png) The picture illustrates how related groups are matched. For simplicity's sake there are only 3 groups in the picture, but in reality there could be N groups of SERP items in the database.

Say i have one group / keyword (group = keyword) and i want to find all matching groups which have at least 3 (N) matches with any urls from a given group. Those groups should also have at least 3 (N) any matching urls between each other.

Same criteria, but now we don't have a starting group and we want to group all groups against each other.

How could i achieve this task? Do i need to use CROSS JOIN?

**Update**

Following query seems to return a set of matching groups for a given group with id 11, but it does not check that each group from returned set is matched against each other.

```
SELECT sr.SerpResultsGroupId, sr1.SerpResultsGroupId
  FROM SerpResults sr
  INNER JOIN SerpResults sr1 ON sr.Url = sr1.Url
  WHERE sr.SerpResultsGroupId != sr1.SerpResultsGroupId
  AND sr.SerpResultsGroupId = 11
  GROUP BY sr.SerpResultsGroupId, sr1.SerpResultsGroupId
  HAVING COUNT(sr1.SerpResultsGroupId) >= 3
```

Comment: Your illustration makes no sense (at least to me).  Edit your question and include sample data and desired results in the question.

Comment: **(1)** What database are you using? **(2)** How do you want the result set to look like ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i've updated the question. Does it look any better?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, (1) - MS SQL 2008 R2, (2) i would like to get sets of matched groups, ex:
Set 1:
- keyword / group 1
- keyword / group 3
- keyword / group 16
Set 2:
- keyword / group 2
- keyword / group 117
etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified solution for use-case of 3 common items.
Related groups will have the same **rnk**.

```
select         t.*

from          (select    count (*) over (partition by   s1.SERP_item,s2.SERP_item,s3.SERP_item) as cnt
                         ,rank  ()  over (order by      s1.SERP_item,s2.SERP_item,s3.SERP_item) as rnk

                        ,s1.SERP_Group
                        ,s1.SERP_item   as SERP_item1
                        ,s2.SERP_item   as SERP_item2
                        ,s3.SERP_item   as SERP_item3

                from            SERP as s1

                        join    SERP as s2

                        on      s2.SERP_Group = s1.SERP_Group 
                            and s2.SERP_item  > s1.SERP_item

                        join    SERP as s3

                        on      s3.SERP_Group = s2.SERP_Group 
                            and s3.SERP_item  > s2.SERP_item
                ) t

where       t.cnt > 1

order by    t.rnk
;
```

---

```
cnt rnk SERP_Group  SERP_item1  SERP_item2  SERP_item3
--- --- ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2   30  139         4           17          19
2   30  744         4           17          19
4   36  372         4           31          33
4   36  375         4           31          33
4   36  391         4           31          33
4   36  408         4           31          33
```

---

Generic solution for **n** common items.
Related groups will have the same **rnk**.

```
with        t (SERP_Group,SERP_item,n,SERP_items)
            as
            (
                select  SERP_Group,SERP_item,1 as n,cast (SERP_item as varchar(max))
                from    SERP

                union all

                select  s.SERP_Group,s.SERP_item,t.n+1,SERP_items + ',' + cast (s.SERP_item as varchar(max))

                from            t 
                        join    SERP s 
                        on      s.SERP_Group = t.SERP_Group
                            and s.SERP_item  > t.SERP_item
                            and t.n          < 3
            )

select      cnt
           ,rnk
           ,SERP_Group
           ,SERP_items

from       (select         t.*
                           ,rank  ()  over (order by     SERP_items)    as rnk
                           ,count (*) over (partition by SERP_items)    as cnt

            from           t

            where          t.n = 3
            ) t

where       t.cnt > 1

order by    t.rnk
;
```

---

```
cnt rnk SERP_Group  SERP_items 
--- --- ----------  ---------- 
2   107 139         4,17,19          
2   107 744         4,17,19          
4   113 372         4,17,19          
4   113 375         4,31,33          
4   113 391         4,31,33          
4   113 408         4,31,33
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to run this against live data and post the results.

Comment: i'm a bit confused how to adapt the queries to my db schema. I have two tables: SerpResultsGroup and SerpResults.

Comment: @AndreyMamon, you were talking about SERP Group and Serp Item - where are they located?

Comment: i've added db schema picture to illustrate.

Comment: @AndreyMamon, if I got it correctly - SerpResults.SerpResultsGroupId is **SERP_Group** and SerpResults.Id is **Serp_Item**

Answer (score 1):

Use `Group by` and `Having` Clause

```
Group by SERP_Group,SERP_item
Having count(1) >= 3
```

Comment: i need to match groups against each other, simple grouping won't work i think. I've updated the question with additional information.